# how does light effect depth from camera?

Tags: ros, camera, realsense, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi guys ,

just a general question i wanted to ask, that i am using intel realsense r200 camera and i am doing color tracking with it... i just want to know because of different light environments , my depth changes, is it normal ?? to be more clear cant i make my program more general to all light conditions????
i see that inside the room the depth is perfect but when the camera is exposed to bright white light in front of it,, its not able to give depth properly ..

any suggestions !!

thanks guys

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260854/how-does-light-effect-depth-from-camera-!!/) by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2017-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Realsense is a stereo camera that computes depth based on the two IR cameras on a onboard [ASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) . It additionally illuminates the scene with an IR pattern to add structure for the stereo matching. This allows use indoor and outdoor, but within the limits of physics of course.

There are different setting presets available that provide different trade-offs between speckles/noise and depth image density. You can test those with the example programs that come with librealsense.

If for your application both the scene and sensor are static you could also compute the depth image yourself, possibly taking multiple exposures etc., but that is pretty involved.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on 2017-05-02**:
thanks for your response !! so you mean i need to know the environment light condition and robot will behave in particularly that light condition,, its very difficult to get depth when the object is in front of bright sunlight it just gives outline of the object not the depth exactly

**Comment by [zubair](https://answers.ros.org/users/29938/zubair/) on 2017-05-02**:
in conclusion to your response i  guess the light condition should be know prior to get a good depth and do setting (camera ) accordingly ..